# \hyperlink adds unwanted space around images. How to get rid of it?

Tags: spacing, hyperref

With pdflatex the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
        \hyperlink{bar}{
          \begin{tikzpicture}
                \filldraw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
          \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \hyperlink{bar}{
          \begin{tikzpicture}
                \filldraw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
          \end{tikzpicture}
        }\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}
              \filldraw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
              \filldraw (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
        \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{figure}
 \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

yields a slide where spacing between the hyperlinked `tikzpicture` environments (upper row) is larger than the spacing between the non-hyperlinked `tikzpicture` environments (lower row). The same effect can also be seen when using e.g. `\includegraphics`. Is there a way to get rid of this spacing?

Comment: No, the spaces are coming from your spurious spaces in your setup. Welcome to TeX.SE, by the way

Comment: See [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `tikzpicture` environment is basically like a letter/character box, so having no `%` after a `\end{tikzpicture}` will cause spacings as well as `\hyperlink{bar}{` with the line break will add spurious spaces.

If any of those spacings should be 'killed', you have to place `%` after `\hyperlink{bar}{` and  after the links and after `\end{tikzpicture}` of the none-linked environments, as well as say `\offinterlineskip` -- the four images are contigious then.

See the differences between both methods.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{figure}
    \hyperlink{bar}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[blue] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }
    \hyperlink{bar}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[red] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    } 

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \filldraw[yellow] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \filldraw[green] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{figure}

  \begin{figure}
    \hyperlink{bar}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[blue] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    \hyperlink{bar}{%
      \begin{tikzpicture}
        \filldraw[red] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    }%
    \offinterlineskip% Only within groups!!!

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \filldraw[yellow] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \filldraw[green] (0,0) -- (0,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,0) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
  \end{figure}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]